# WCF - How to automatically subscribe endpoint address behind load balancer?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, message-bus

I've created a mini message bus which runs operations on its clients (e.g. clear their cache). I'm trying to make it dynamic so every new application added will automatically subscribe its endpoint to the bus so the bus could communicate with it later on. Applications are behind a load balancer, so I've tried to subscribe with an explicit ip of each new application. I've got the error of 'Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority', because the certificate was issued to domain name, not to IP and I'm on TransportWithMessageCredential security mode (I prefer not to use the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback trick because it applies to entire application).

Any idea how could I achieve this dynamic behavior so every new server added could subscribe to the message bus and the message bus could run operations specifically on that server node?

Comment: Have you tried dynamically creating the entire service? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx   (seems like you have, just want to cover all bases)

Comment: @Pseudonym - Even if I create the service dynamically, I still want to register the service endpoint to the main message bus, the problem is how to call that specific endpoint (which is behind a load balancer) from the bus without using its IP address?

Comment: I am guessing there are _agents_ that execute those operations on clients. Why cannot the agents connect to the outside world (aka **mini-message bus command and control center**) rather than the other way in? Inbound connection will require specific config changes on the Load Balancer.